# google doc reader : remove the option "Open in new window"

Tags: javascript, google-docs-api

Is there any way of removing or disabling the 'open in new window' icon of google doc reader( when used in embedded mode interface) through the embedded code(which we write for [embedding documents](https://docs.google.com/viewer)) or javascript/jquery?

Comment: For someone who hasn't used this before its not very clear what you mean (to me at least). Could you clarify a bit further?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is any standard method. If you really want to do it, then you can try something like this.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div style='position:relative;'>
            <div style='background-color:White;top:0px; height: 47px; position: absolute; left:0px; width: 100%;'></div>
            <div style='background-color:LightGray;top:47px; height: 5px; position: absolute; left:0px; width: 100%;'></div>
            <iframe src='http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf&embedded=true' width='100%' height='100%' style='border: none;'/>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>No, as I understand the embedded code runs in an iFrame from another domain (Google), so you cannot use script to change the contents of that.</strike>

Perhaps, try adding `&rm=minimal` to the url of your embedded document.

[Embed editable Google Docs spreadsheet without header & toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8174410/embed-editable-google-docs-spreadsheet-without-header-toolbar)