# Embed Google doc in mysite

Tags: embed, google-sheets, google-docs

I am trying to embed a Google document into mysite. But the problem I run into is the toolbar shows up. Now I went through the answer suggested here - 
[Embed editable Google Docs spreadsheet without header & toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8174410/embed-editable-google-docs-spreadsheet-without-header-toolbar)
And the answer works fine if your url is like

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/a/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AuPY7UMZ5i78dGstaWh0b2h1ZmdyME9mSmpFMk5MYmc&usp=drive_web#gid=0;embedded=true" style="width:680px; height:860px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

But my urls are like this

```
<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/a/website.com/file/d/0B-PY7UMZ5i78UW5aUk5neW5mMTg/edit?usp=sharing;embedded=true" style="width:680px; height:860px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

So instead of starting with docs.google.com, it starts with drive.google.com. And adding rm=minimal anywhere did not help.

Moreover the look of docs.google.com seems to be different compared to drive.google.com

Answer (score 1):

You can get the code right from Sheets. Try File - Publish to Web...

In the Publish to Web dialog, select "HTML to embed in a page", as shown below:

[image: dialog]

Just copy the resulting HTML. With "widget=true", you will have a title but no tool bar.