# How to keep Google Sheet images clickable with menu hidden (rm=minimal)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to hide the menus etc in a Google Sheet from the user (see [Embed editable Google Docs spreadsheet without header & toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8174410/embed-editable-google-docs-spreadsheet-without-header-toolbar))

I use `?rm=minimal` but when I do this all scripts attached to images stop operating.  Is there a way around this restriction?

Thanks

Comment: Seems like a limitation of spreadsheet.
https://productforums.google.com/forum/?hl=es#!topic/docs/ZPjIlFdDANI;context-place=topicsearchin/docs/category$3Achrome-os%7Csort:relevance%7Cspell:false