# Embed specific range from Google Sheets in website so that it is editable by website users

Tags: iframe, google-sheets, embed

I want to embed a specific range of cells from a Google Docs spreadsheet (or if that doesn't work the whole sheet without header and toolbar) in a website, so that any website visitor can input their data.

I know how to embed a specific range of cells an html table, but that doesn't allow website users to edit the sheet.

A similar question was asked several years ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8174410/embed-editable-google-docs-spreadsheet-without-header-toolbar?rq=1) but the suggested solution doesn't seem to work anymore.

Answer (score 2):

I called this the htmlSpreadsheet you can use as a dialog or deploy as webapp the doGet is already to go.  It's still a pretty simple app.  There's a lot of room for customization.

Here's the code.gs file:

```
function onOpen()
{
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('HTML Spreadsheet')
    .addItem('Run Spreadsheet in Dialog', 'htmlSpreadsheet')
    .addToUi();
}

var SSID='SpreadSheetID';
var sheetName='Sheet1';

function htmlSpreadsheet(mode)
{
  var mode=(typeof(mode)!='undefined')?mode:'dialog';
  var br='<br />';
  var s='';
  var hdrRows=1;
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById(SSID);
  var sht=ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var rng=sht.getDataRange();
  var rngA=rng.getValues();
  s+='<table>';
  for(var i=0;i<rngA.length;i++)
  {
    s+='<tr>';
    for(var j=0;j<rngA[i].length;j++)
    {
      if(i<hdrRows)
      {
        s+='<th id="cell' + i + j + '">' + '<input id="txt' + i + j + '" type="text" value="' + rngA[i][j] + '" size="10" onChange="updateSS(' + i + ',' + j + ');" />' + '</th>';
      } 
      else
      {
        s+='<td id="cell' + i + j + '">' + '<input id="txt' + i + j + '" type="text" value="' + rngA[i][j] + '" size="10" onChange="updateSS(' + i + ',' + j + ');" />' + '</th>';
      }
    }
    s+='</tr>';
  }
  s+='</table>';
  //s+='<div id="success"></div>';
  s+='</body></html>';
  switch (mode)
  {
    case 'dialog':
      var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('htmlss').setWidth(1000).setHeight(450);
      userInterface.append(s);
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, 'Spreadsheet Data for ' + ss.getName() + ' Sheet: ' + sht.getName());
      break;
    case 'web':
      var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('htmlss').setWidth(1000).setHeight(450);
      return userInterface.append(s).setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
   }
}

function updateSpreadsheet(i,j,value)
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById(SSID);
  var sht=ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var rng=sht.getDataRange();
  var rngA=rng.getValues();
  rngA[i][j]=value;
  rng.setValues(rngA);
  var data = {'message':'Cell[' + Number(i + 1) + '][' + Number(j + 1) + '] Has been updated', 'ridx': i, 'cidx': j};
  return data;
}

function doGet()
{
  var output=htmlSpreadsheet('web');
  return output;
}
```

This is the htmlss.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function() {

    });
    function updateSS(i,j)
    {
      var str='#txt' + String(i) + String(j);
      var value=$(str).val();
      $(str).css('background-color','#ffff00');
      google.script.run
         .withSuccessHandler(successHandler)
         .updateSpreadsheet(i,j,value)
    }
    function successHandler(data)
    {
      $('#success').text(data.message);
      $('#txt' + data.ridx + data.cidx).css('background-color','#ffffff');
    }
    console.log('My Code');
    </script>
    <style>
      th{text-align:left}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="success"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm using Wordpress so I think your solution is not applicable to my case, unfortunately. Is there any way to do this using Wordpress?

Comment: Not so.  Just deploy as webapp and iframe it into your site. [Here's an example of a similar situation.](http://www.wiechman4lakewood.com/resources/city-council-archives)  This is a site that I manage.  It's a wordpress site and the archive minutes and archive video are webapps that have been iframed into the site.

Comment: I like this!  Note that it does not update the end user's cells containing formulas, so just a straight edit from the user's standpoint without the benefit of formulas, but it does limit the user's capabilities.  It also seems to change the cell's formatting to Automatic on a custom date format. I have not tried it for other formats  If the sheet in question has no formulas, then all is good.  I am not aware of a way to know which cells have a formula which reference a given cell, without looping through all of them, though.

Answer (score 1):

Following post will be helpfull:
https://support.google.com/docs/answer/37579?hl=fr&ref_topic=2818998

And with some added value, the following is the template you may want to try, where ------ is specific code to your sheet

```
<iframe style="border: 0;" src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/-----/pubhtml?gid=--------&amp;range=C2:E&amp;chrome=false&amp;single=true&amp;widget=false&amp;headers=false" width="800" height="750" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes"><span data-mce-type="bookmark" style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; overflow: hidden; line-height: 0;" class="mce_SELRES_start">﻿</span><span data-mce-type="bookmark" style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; overflow: hidden; line-height: 0;" class="mce_SELRES_start">﻿</span><span data-mce-type="bookmark" style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; overflow: hidden; line-height: 0;" class="mce_SELRES_start">﻿</span></iframe>
```