# How to add/give toolbars google spreadsheet to blogspot post

Tags: toolbar, spreadsheet, blogger

i already embed my spreadsheet to blogspot's post but spreadsheet's toolbar is not appear
[image]

how do i add the entire google spreadsheet toolbar to my blogspot post ? or my embed code is wrong

especially what I need are the filters that I have installed in the spreadsheet in each column

Comment: Please read [Docs Help page](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/183965#zippy=%2Cedit-embedded-spreadsheets).

Comment: i read that help page and arrived at this page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8174410/embed-editable-google-docs-spreadsheet-without-header-toolbar

Comment: and i got some idea thanks @web_xaser