# Embed editable Google Sheets without Cell Coordinates

Tags: html, google-sheets, embed

I wish to embed a spreadsheet made on Google Sheets such that it is editable and as "clean" as possible, for this I want to find a way to embed an editable sheet which also doesn't show the Cell numbers or letters (on the side and above).

I have arrived at two different outputs which approximate what I want. By using the link to share with others as such:

```
<center><iframe width="1000" height="700"  src="[GOOGLE SPREADSHEETS LINK TO SHARE WITH OTHERS]?single=false&widget=false&headers=false&rm=minimal"></iframe></center>
```

Leads to the following output **which is editable**
[image]

By using the link given when you select "publish to the web" as such:

```
<center><iframe width="1000" height="500"<iframe src="[GOOGLE SPREADHSHEETS LINK TO PUBLISH TO THE WEB]pubhtml?widget=true&amp;headers=false"></iframe></center>
```

Leads to the following **which does not have the cell coordinates** but is **not editable**:
[image]

Note that: Both HTML codes have the parameter `&headers=false` which is used for getting rid of the coordinates (it works in the second but not the first)

Is there a way to "combine" both outputs and get an embedding such as the one I am looking for?

Comment: removing cols and rows reference defeats the purpose of having an editable spreadsheet, what's your motivation?

Comment: @DavidSalomon it doesn't defeat all the purpose. I would like to be able to edit the cells which are shown on the website but not add any new rows or columns.

Comment: There are many applications for this.  In my case, a search bar that populates data based on dropdown selection.  Would be nice for it to look like it is part of the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8174410/embed-editable-google-docs-spreadsheet-without-header-toolbar#:%7E:text=Note%20that%20these%20query%20strings%20are%20only%20supported%20for%20the%20%22Published%22%20sheets%2C%20not%20the%20editable%20links%20discussed%20in%20other%20answers.) and it looks like these [parameters](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/183965?#zippy=%2Cedit-embedded-spreadsheets) are only supported for the “Published” sheets and not the editable link.

You can request this feature to be available through Google Sheets by going to a Google Sheet file, click on ‘Help’ > ‘Help Sheets improve’ and give a description of your request.